# How to make a bot available to multiple users on blocking operations? python, aiogram, pytube, ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, telegram, pytube, aiogram

I'm trying to deal with multithreading and asynchrony, but I can't figure out how to deal with this situation.

There is a telegram bot that downloads videos from YouTube and cuts only the first minute of the video into a separate file. Pytube and ffmpeg are used. The second bot user does not receive any response from the bot while the tasks of the first one are running. How to deal with such difficulties?

```
import subprocess

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.utils import executor
from pytube import YouTube
import time

API_TOKEN = 'tkn'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

video_folder = 'video/'


@dp.message_handler()
async def start_convert(message: types.Message):
    url = message.text
    yt = YouTube(url)

    await message.reply('accepted')

    video_name = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S") + '.mp4'

    video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    video.download(video_folder, filename=video_name)

    await message.reply('downloaded')

    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-hide_banner', '-loglevel', 'error', '-i', f'{video_folder}{video_name}',
                     '-ss', '0', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-c:a', 'aac', '-b:v', '5M', '-to', '60',
                     f'{video_folder}1_min_{video_name}'])

    await message.reply('trimmed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

This is a code template.
In the current form, I want to understand how to implement the task correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need multithreading to solve your problem: asyncio is more than enough

A second or third user that will want to use the bot while the first user has not finished will not be able to use the bot because pyube and the ffmpeg subprocess are both blocking/sync, rather than async

You need to run pytube in an asyncio executor like this:

```
...

this_loop=asyncio.get_running_loop()
pytube_job=this_loop.run_in_executor(None,pytube_stuff,arg1,arg2,argn)
await pytube_job
results=pytube_job.result()

...
```

And for ffmpeg, you shoud use the async version of subprocess, like this:

```
...

ffmpeg_line=['ffmpeg','-hide_banner','-loglevel','error','-i',f'{video_folder}{video_name}','-ss', '0', '-c:v', 'libx264', '-c:a', 'aac', '-b:v', '5M', '-to', '60',f'{video_folder}1_min_{video_name}']

proc=await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*ffmpeg_line,stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

proc_result=await proc.communicate()
proc_stdout=proc_result[0].decode()
proc_stderr=proc_result[1].decode()

...
```

For more info about all of this, read the asyncio documentation